# Borrar filas de la base de datos

Tags: sql

Tengo una base de datos con tres tablas y sus respectivas columnas

1-actores (nombre, país, numerareisS)
2-películas (nombre, género, duración)
3-participación (nombrePelicula, nombreActor, papel, premios)

Estoy anclado en un ejercicio donde me piden que borre todas las pelis de la base de datos que no han ganado ningun premio.

Adjunto codigo de las tablas para que se pueda ver la relacion entre PARTICIPACION i PELICULAS ya que nombrePelicula y nombreActor son "foreign key"

```
CREATE TABLE PELICULA(
    nom VARCHAR(200) PRIMARY KEY,
    genere VARCHAR(200),
    durada INT
    
); CREATE TABLE ACTOR(
    nom VARCHAR(200) PRIMARY KEY,
    paisNaixement VARCHAR(200),
    numPelicules INT
    
); CREATE TABLE PARTICIPA(
    PRIMARY KEY(nomPelicula, nomActor),
    nomPelicula VARCHAR(200),
    nomActor VARCHAR(200),
    paper VARCHAR(50),
    FOREIGN KEY(nomPelicula) REFERENCES PELICULA(nom),
    FOREIGN KEY(nomActor) REFERENCES ACTOR(nom)
)
```

El tema es que tengo el siguiente código, pero no me acaba de funcionar y no entiendo/encuentro como poder borrar de la base de datos las películas que no han ganado ningún premio.

```
DELETE FROM PARTICIPA
INNER JOIN PELICULA ON PELICULA.nom = PARTICIPA.nomPelicula
WHERE PARTICIPA.premi is NULL
```

Podéis ayudarme?

Comment: Que resultado obtienes?

Comment: Te falta agregarle la segunda tabla: `DELETE FROM PARTICIPA, PELICULA`. Por otro lado ¿Porque estas creando 2 PKs?(nomPelicula, nomActor)

Comment: Obtengo esto: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'INNER JOIN PELICULA ON PELICULA.nom = PARTICIPA.nomPelicula
WHERE PARTICIPA.pre' en la linea 2

Comment: Dices que lo haga asi?

DELETE FROM PARTICIPA, PELICULA
WHERE PARTICIPA.premi is NULL

Comment: @Joan ¿Alguna respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 0):

lo que noto aquí es que no tienes un estado para las películas puedes poner donde pongas "Premios INT (1)  " donde tenga 2 estados: "1: Película con premio" , "2: Película sin premio" la cual puedas tener un comparativo donde poder discernir las películas y eliminar las que te piden por ese parámetro.

Comment: No entiendo tu respuesta, le estas diciendo que agrege un campo estado para poder borrar los registros?

Comment: Dices que lo haga asi?

DELETE FROM PARTICIPA, PELICULA
WHERE PARTICIPA.premi is NULL

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que te falta por definir la columna premi en la tabla participa.

la tabla participa te quedará del siguiente modo:

```sql
CREATE TABLE PARTICIPA(
    PRIMARY KEY(nomPelicula, nomActor),
    nomPelicula VARCHAR(200),
    nomActor VARCHAR(200),
    paper VARCHAR(50),
    premi VARCHAR(50), -- SI QUIERES QUE SEA UNA CADENA
    FOREIGN KEY(nomPelicula) REFERENCES PELICULA(nom),
    FOREIGN KEY(nomActor) REFERENCES ACTOR(nom)
)
```

Así te funcionaría. De todos modos yo te recomendaría que no usaras los nombres como clave, porque muchas veces, con acentos, espacios, orden de nombres y apellidos y demás suele ser difícil realizar búsquedas

Comment: Buenas, tenia que haberlo puesto antes. La columna premi se añade despues de crear las tablas con: ALTER TABLE PARTICIPA ADD premi VARCHAR(50);

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver el problema en SQL, el enfoque es muy similar al que usas en lenguaje coloquial, ajustando la descripción a lo técnicamente posible.

Veamos como hacerlo; tu descripción dice:

> borre todas las pelis de la base de datos que no han ganado ningun (sic) premio

Si lo pensamos un poco, para comenzar, en tu estructura no se registra si una película ganó un premio, lo único que se registra es si un actor que participó en una película ganó un premio, por lo que lo primero que debemos hacer es *traducir* la expresión a algo como:

**Borrar todas las películas que no tengan participaciones de actores que hayan ganado premios**

Si damos una vuelta de tuerca más, esto sería:

**Borrar todas las películas para las que no exista una participación de actor que haya ganado premios**

Y esa es la definición que necesitamos para expresarlo en SQL, basándonos en una cláusula **`not exists`** para:

### Borrar filas de una tabla cuando no existen registros vinculados que cumplan una condición en otra tabla

La consulta que hace el trabajo sería similar a esta:

```
delete
  from PELICULA
 where not exists (select *
                     from PARTICIPA
                    where PARTICIPA.nomPelicula = PELICULA.nom
                      and PARTICIPA.premios is not null
                  )
```

La idea es que la sub-consulta, que se va filtrando por cada registro de la tabla `PELICULA`, nos devuelva al menos un registro de `PARTICIPA` que **si tenga premios**.

- Si nos devuelve por lo menos un registro, `exists` devolverá verdadero, y al negarlo, esta película será excluida del borrado.
- En cambio, si no devuelve ningún registro, exists devolverá `falso`, al negarlo es `verdadero` y esta película es eliminada.

El resultado es que borramos todas las películas que no tienen premios (volviendo a la redacción original).

OJO, que no has incluido el campo `premios` en tu script, por tanto no sé si la columna es `not null`, o su tipo de datos, por lo que probablemente haya que ajustar la última línea del query para obtener el resultado.

Comment: Buenas, lo acabo de pasar a mi BBDD y me salta el siguiente error: 

#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jagudosa`.`PARTICIPA`, CONSTRAINT `PARTICIPA_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`nomPelicula`) REFERENCES `PELICULA` (`nom`))

Comment: Excelente, significa que si funciona, pero tienes otros problemas. En este caso, una llave foránea de la tabla `PARTICIPA` que no tiene borrados en cascada. Para mantener las cosas simples, sugiero que borres la definición actual y la cambies por un `foreign key` que incluya la cláusula `on update cascade`

Comment: No entiendo como incluir el on update cascade. No tendria que ser on delete cascade? Puedes ponerme el codigo para que lo pueda ver como queda?

Comment: ya lo tengo. Gracias!!

Comment: Si, mi error, quise decir `on delete cascade`.

Comment: @Joan recuerda marcar como respuesta aceptada, si te funciono